# THREE.js GLTFLoader not rendering with react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, three.js, gltf

am quite new to both react and three.js, im trying to render a .gltf file using the method  `const Loader = new GLTFLoader()` however when the website is rendered and i view it in browser i see the error message, **An error happened SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**, if anyone would know what direction to point me in that would be great.

here's the code

rende.js:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
export default class Rende extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(0x424242, 1);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.getElementById("scene").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(
      "untitled.gltf",
      (gltf) => {
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
      },
      (xhr) => {
        console.log(`${(xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100}% loaded`);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error("An error happened", error);
      }
    );
 
  }
  render() {
    return <div id="scene" className="potato"></div>;
  }
}
```

and the coresponding component page

home.jsx:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {" "}
      <div key={1} className="class">
        tagline
      </div>
      <Rende />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

if anyone can help that would be much apreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Just a suggestion:  Try to check the validity of your GLTF to see if it has any problem. You can do it by draggin it into this `khronos` website https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/.   Sometimes the model has some problems that prevent it from loading correctly that you may need to solve first.

Comment: Also if you open your `.gltf` in some text editor, is that a valid JSON file?   Can you see some weird `<` charter where shouldn't be? (based on the error should be in the first line of the file)   Seems like your gltf is not a valid JSON looking the error...

Comment: thank you i checked khronos and it was a valid gltf file and i also looked at the json it didn't contain any irregular JSON char's

Comment: from the examples ive seen the path seems to be correct, i have tried multiple variations of the path, and none of them seen to be working, i dont think its a page not found error i instead think its a parsing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Maybe the path of your model is wrong?

###### I think you should fix it with a relative path, or the right absolute one.

---

*It happened to me firsthand when I worked with threejs at the beginning and was writing the wrong path for my `.gltf` in a single-page-app*

---

##### Replication of the error and reasons

I made a [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/three-js-import-gltf-error-te1zwg?file=/src/index.js:2331-2354) of a *"Three.js import GLTF"* sandbox on codesandbox, where I replaced the path with a random, wrong one.

If you open the console (in the sandbox [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/three-js-import-gltf-error-te1zwg?file=/src/index.js:2331-2354)), you will see your same error.

This is because the fetch still has the status `200` but with `HTML` instead of your model's JSON,

> *due to the wrong path and the behavior of the server of a single page application, which, generally, returns the index.html, unless it is a path belonging to one of the assets, by default with reactjs and other libraries/frameworks.*

*From the sandbox*
[image]

Since the path is wrong, the server returns your html instead of your model, so the JSON parser throws your same error, because actually, the first char recived is `<`.

*...as you can see in this screen from the browser dev-tools > Network tab, while running the sandbox*

[image]

---

##### Conclusion

Try to check out the network devtools while running your website to check if your `.gltf` fetch response is `HTML` (intead of your model JSON).
If so, your model path is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you i seem to have found the error, it was a combination of the camera being too zoomed in, the model being the wrong path and the textrue not loading in, that you very much for helping me solve this!

Comment: I'm glad I helped you!   Ps. Don't use answers for something like this :) Use instead a comment like this on the specific post of interest.  Answer your questions only if you find the solution yourself and want to share it with the community :) Bye